# using Taylor's Theorem to find region of convergence of series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXski.jpg)

I am a third year Electrical engineering student, and I was going through one of the example from my math module lecture notes but couldn't understand the solution printed on the note. Could anyone please help me out? the link above is the image of part of the handout that contains the question. I don't know how to get 1 as the answer of part (b). the 'an' I circled on the sheet, does it mean 'un'? Could someone give me a step by step solution of how it gets to that function (where I underlined). where did the Z term go?

thank you.

Comment: Yes, it means $u_n$.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to simplify that function to what it shows on the sheet? and how did the z term get canceled out?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on.  Just a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two typos.  They have named

$$
a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}
$$

the coefficient of $z^n$, then the part with the limit should read

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n+1)}{(-1)^{n} n}\right| = 1.
$$

Comment: that explained everything, thank you so much! :)